# Gocql configuration issue when connecting to YugabyteDB in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm currently trying out the [Yugabyte k8s operator deployment](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/deploy/kubernetes/single-zone/oss/yugabyte-operator/) with my app, which is using the [Go Yugabyte cql driver](https://github.com/yugabyte/gocql). I have the app working, connecting, and querying seemingly fine, using a single dns `yb-tservers.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local` that resolves to 3 ip addresses. My app is in a different k8s namespace on the same cluster. However, the app is logging the following from the client driver:

```
gocql: events: unable to fetch host info for (10.x.x.1:9042): host not found in peers table
gocql: events: unable to fetch host info for (10.x.x.2:9042): host not found in peers table
```

It seems to be doing that for 2 of the 3 ip addresses resolved from the dns. Are there any obvious go-to configuration issues to look at here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the tserver addresses with their headless service dns names like below and it should work:

```
yb-tserver-0.yb-tservers.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
yb-tserver-1.yb-tservers.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
yb-tserver-2.yb-tservers.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```